# What is the Firebase Authentication SDK for Windows and MacOS apps?

Tags: firebase-authentication

Develop Unity apps that run on desktops (Windows, MacOS). I am developing a Unity app that runs on desktop (Windows, MacOS).
If I want to use Firebase Authentication for this app (on the above OS), which SDK provided by Firebase should I use?
(Firebase Unity SDK only works with Android and iOS apps?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Firebase documentation for setting it up for Unity, it contains a section on [setting up a desktop workflow (beta)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#desktop-workflow) that says:

> **Caution: Firebase Unity SDK desktop support is a beta feature. This feature is intended only for workflows during the development of your game, not for publicly shipping code.**
>
> When you're creating a game, it's often much easier to test your game in the Unity editor and on desktop platforms first, then deploy and test on mobile devices later in development. To support this workflow, we provide a subset of the Firebase Unity SDKs which can run on Windows, macOS, Linux, and from within the Unity editor.

So Firebase's SDK for Unity *does* support development workflows on Windows, macOS and Linux desktop systems. It does not support building release versions for these platforms though.

---

So if you want to develop a game **on** a desktop machine, the Firebase SDK for Unity would be the easiest way to do that.

If you want to develop a game targeted **for** desktop machines though, that is not supported through the Firebase SDK. The usual fallback would be to communicate directly with the [Firebase REST APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) from your Unity code.